# Excel2007 Is it possible add/remove data to/from pivot table programmatically?

Tags: vba, excel-2007

Is it possible add/remove data to/from pivot table programmatically?

I created a pivot table for historical data.
I need to do what-if analysis.
So, I want the table to be updated automatically when I add/remove new data to/from the data table programmatically.

The first image show my pivot table.

Is it possible add an entry to the pivot table without touching the data source?

I am using excel 2007.

[image: June]

[image: July]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the pivot table by updating the pivot cache, the following code allows multiple pivot table in a sheet to be updated.

```
Sub UpdateDataSource()

  Dim pt As PivotTable
  Dim Data As String

  'Data source of data
  Data = "'Data'!$B:$AB"

    For Each pt In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
      pt.ChangePivotCache _
      ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
      SourceData:=Data)
    Next pt

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to append new data to pivot table, and then remove the new data easy?

Comment: Hi, won't it be better if you just remove/add from the data source instead?